# Angular update from 5 to 6 errors

Tags: angular, rxjs

I followed the update guide as recommend but I am getting some errors I am unsure about.

[image]

People have suggested I install `rxjs-compat` but this just gives more errors:

[image]

Here is my package.json I have stripped out anything that is not needed or can do without to try find find the culprit of my issue

```
{
  "name": "verado",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@moltin/sdk": "^3.8.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/graceful-fs": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "angular-cc-library": "^1.2.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: installing rxjs-compat is the right approach, because it will solve your import paths. The second errors seem not to be relaated to rxjs?

Comment: what are the steps can you please add that information

Comment: I used the `ng update` command and adjusted my code to use the new pipe syntax which I was already using

Comment: @Riscie You are right but upon doing a load of googling I am still unsure what it could be I am thinking something todo with web pack?

Comment: is the graceful-fs package there? do you maybe need to npm install again?

Comment: I can confirm graceful-fs and node-localstorage is indeed in my ./node_modules and a fresh install still gives me the second error in my OP

Comment: Upgrade `ng-bootstrap` to 2.0.0. You should only need `rxjs-compat` if your dependencies themselves haven't been updated for rxjs 6.

Comment: @SeanBright This fixed some errors and I have removed rxjs-compat but still getting the second error in my OP

Comment: `ngx-select-ex` has not been updated for rxjs 6, so you still need `rxjs-compat`.

Comment: Fundamentally, this is just your run-of-the-mill dependency problem. You could try posting your `package.json` if someone really wanted to fix this for you, but at the end of the day you need to evaluate your dependencies and work out which need to be upgraded/removed in order to get things working for you. There is no objective "fix" for this.

Comment: @SeanBright Your comment isn't very constructive as many people will encounter issues when upgrading to angular 6 so I think this will be useful resource for anyone else encountering similar issues. I have added my package.json to my OP if would like to take a look I'd be most grateful. I have actually removed most deps and really just using angular so I don't my deps are the issue

Comment: @JoeHill, I upgraded an application from Angular 5 to 6 without an issue, so some combination of your dependencies & node & npm is causing your problems. I'm sorry that you don't feel that is a constructive comment, but it doesn't make it any less true.

Comment: @SeanBright Thanks for the help 

Comment: Would you mind trying to recreate a minimal example of the error on stackblitz?
https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with the `@moltin/js-sdk` dependency loading `node-localstorage` in the browser which made the complier throw a vague error. `graceful-fs` is not the culprit only a symptom of the above.

As a workaround I have added:

`"paths": {
    "node-localstorage": ["noop.js"]
}`

noop.js contains:

`export const noop = () => undefined;`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing node_modules and reinstalling with `npm i`, it did fix all my errors.

Comment: FWIW, [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci) will clean things up for you, eliminating the need to manually delete `node_modules`.